# Finite descent of a semi-Fredholm operator

Tags: operator-theory

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operators on a Banach space $X$.Let $K$ be a compact operator on $X$. $T$ and $K$ be commuting operators. If $T$ is lower semi-Fredholm and descent of $T$ is finite.

I want to prove that descent of $(T+K)$ is finite.